# What does the AND operator mean when applied to pointers in linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to comprehend the C code written to detect and remove a loop in a linked list (taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-and-remove-loop-in-a-linked-list/)). While everything else makes sense to me, I am unable to understand what is going on inside the  `while` statement. More specifically, **how does the logical AND behave when applied to pointer structures?**

```
while (slow_p && fast_p && fast_p->next)
```

A hare and tortoise approach has been followed here wherein we use two pointers, one fast and one slow.

```
/* Link list node */
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
}; 

/* Function to remove loop. Used by detectAndRemoveLoop() */
void removeLoop(struct Node *, struct Node *); 

/* This function detects and removes loop in the list 
  If loop was there in the list then it returns 1, 
  otherwise returns 0 */

int detectAndRemoveLoop(struct Node *list) 
{ 
    struct Node  *slow_p = list, *fast_p = list;

while (slow_p && fast_p && fast_p->next) 
{ 
    slow_p = slow_p->next; 
    fast_p  = fast_p->next->next; 

    /* If slow_p and fast_p meet at some point then there 
       is a loop */
    if (slow_p == fast_p) 
    { 
        removeLoop(slow_p, list); 

        /* Return 1 to indicate that loop is found */
        return 1; 
    } 
} 

/* Return 0 to indeciate that ther is no loop*/
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The condition checks three pointers for nulls. It fails on first null value. The condition will not continue evaluation after it encounters null.

Comment: But when a loop exists inside a linked list, will any node point to a null? I mean when does the while loop stop. Thanks for explaining the condition, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a condition, that ensures the loop breaks and exits if either of three pointers is `NULL`. A null pointer always evaluates to boolean `false` in C. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer.

With the current logic though, it is likely that none of the pointers would be NULL if a cycle exists in your list because we detect the loop and break out of it. The `fast_p` pointer could be `NULL` only when there is no loop in your list and you just finished traversing the whole list in attempt to finding one.

[image]

The sequence of execution happens as follows

1. `slow_p` will be at node 2 and `fast_p` will be at node 3
2. `slow_p` will be at node 3 and `fast_p` will be at node 5
3. `slow_p` will be at node 4 and `fast_p` would have gone past the cyclic node and would be at node 3 again
4. `slow_p` will be at node 5 and `fast_p` will be at node 5

At this point both these pointers are pointing to the node at the same address, so the address comparison would assert causing the function to break and return the address of `slow_p` which is now *exactly* pointing at the node causing this cyclic loop.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Please forgive my lack of proper fundamentals, but even when both the pointers land at the same node, will they point to a NULL? When do you say they are pointing to a NULL?

Comment: @MaxFrost: See my update that clarifies your question